# GSM not responding to AT commands

Tags: arduino, gsm, sim900

I am using GSM 900A modem which requires 5V Supply. I am connecting it to Arduino UNO. I am giving supply to modem by arduino 5V and GND pin. I am connecting RXD pin to TX(pin 1) of arduino TXD pin to RX(pin 0) of arduino and GND to GND of arduino i.e. pin 14. I am running the basic example codes but GSM is not responding. I have also tried other softwares like Putty but I am unable to write any AT command Please help me. When I tested the modem using this code:

```
/*

 This example tests to see if the modem of the
 GSM shield is working correctly. You do not need
 a SIM card for this example.

 Circuit:
 * GSM shield attached

 Created 12 Jun 2012
 by David del Peral
 modified 21 Nov 2012
 by Tom Igoe

 http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/GSMToolsTestModem

 This sample code is part of the public domain

 */

// libraries
#include <GSM.h>

// modem verification object
GSMModem modem;

// IMEI variable
String IMEI = "";

void setup() {
  // initialize serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }

  // start modem test (reset and check response)
  Serial.print("Starting modem test...");
  if (modem.begin()) {
    Serial.println("modem.begin() succeeded");
  } else {
    Serial.println("ERROR, no modem answer.");
  }
}

void loop() {
  // get modem IMEI
  Serial.print("Checking IMEI...");
  IMEI = modem.getIMEI();

  // check IMEI response
  if (IMEI != NULL) {
    // show IMEI in serial monitor
    Serial.println("Modem's IMEI: " + IMEI);
    // reset modem to check booting:
    Serial.print("Resetting modem...");
    modem.begin();
    // get and check IMEI one more time
    if (modem.getIMEI() != NULL) {
      Serial.println("Modem is functoning properly");
    } else {
      Serial.println("Error: getIMEI() failed after modem.begin()");
    }
  } else {
    Serial.println("Error: Could not get IMEI");
  }
  // do nothing:
  while (true);
}
```

I am getting this output on Serial Monitor for 9600 baud rate:

Starting modem test...ERROR, no modem answer. Checking IMEI...Modem's IMEI: 0 Resetting modem...Modem is functioning properly

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with your supply, try using an adapter, that outputs a current of 500mA to 1A.